# Filter GenericForeignKeyField in django tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

Using GenericForeignKeyField in a django-tastypie resource, is there a way to filter results based on the content_type? I would like to add a filter to the Meta class, just like with a regular field, but I am unable to do it with a GenericForeignKeyField.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up dehydrating the content type by adding this method to my resource

```
def dehydrate(self,bundle):
    bundle.data['type'] = bundle.obj.content_type
    return bundle
```

then I filtered the data on the client side. Its not an ideal solution, but good enough for now